# Limit object dimensions in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

After trying to limit the dragable object dimensions i concluded i need to limit the object's actual bounding box. But after limiting the box the object simple goes over it. How can i re-center the object inside the bounding box? Working example of my problem can be found here : http://jsfiddle.net/hNNk5/ maybe i need to add

```
canvas.renderAll();
```

or something along those lines ?
I have tried all possible combinations. Maybe i can archieve the same thing with coordinates ? Any ideas are welcome

Comment: If you need to limit object dimensions (not movement) — which looks like you do — you'll need to constrain scaleX/scaleY properties of an object (when observing "object:scaling" event).